# Dynamically create camera in the BGE?

Tags: python, game-engine, camera

Is it possible to do this in 2.6? I'm trying to dynamically create cameras. Looking around the API reference I found `KX_Camera` and `Camera`, but they have no constructors or factories, that work at least.

In 2.4 it seems that you could do it, as I believe they have `.new()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
import bge

scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
owner = bge.logic.getCurrentController().owner
cam = scene.addObject("Camera.001", owner , 0)
```

Note that the camera object needs to be on an inactive layer.

To set the active camera in the BGE:

```
bge.logic.getCurrentScene().active_camera = cam
```